# Using Google Cloud Speech API from javascript & Web Audio

Tags: javascript, angular, web-audio-api, google-speech-api

I am trying to send a LINEAR16 PCM encoded audio to Google cloud speech API(using REST API). I am getting audio from microphone using Web Audio API and sending base64 encoded data to the server.  I am getting an empty {} every time.

First I  stored audio buffers  from stream to a array

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ 'audio': <MediaTrackConstraints>{
  echoCancellation: true,
  channelCount: 1,
  sampleRate: 16000,
  sampleSize: 16
}, 'video': false})
.then((stream: MediaStream) => {
  // to store audio chunks
  // Create AUdio Context ANd set Stream
  this.context = new AudioContext();
  this.sourceNode = this.context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  // Processing Node WIll give rAW data IN PCM32 bit format
  this.processor = this.context.createScriptProcessor(8192, 1, 1);
  this.sourceNode.connect(this.processor);
  this.processor.connect(this.context.destination);
  this.processor.onaudioprocess = (e: AudioProcessingEvent) => {
    // Raw Audio IN e.InputBuffer WHich Is A Audio Buffer
    this.buffer.push(e.inputBuffer);
  };
}).catch( () => {
  this.dom.sendNotifications('Warning', 'Failed To Record Audio', 'warning');
});
```

Then I stopped recording audio and appended all AudioBuffers in the array.

```
// Merge Array of Buffers Into single Buffer
const mergedBuffer: AudioBuffer = this.appendBuffers(this.buffer);
// Convert to Int16 Data & base64
const intArray: Int16Array =this.bufferToInt16PCM(mergedBuffer.getChannelData(0));
const base64: string = this.intToBase64(intArray);
this.sendRequestToGoogleAPI(base64);
// Release Resources
this.processor.disconnect();
this.sourceNode.disconnect();
this.context.close();
this.buffer = [];
```

This is how I Appended the buffers (appendBuffer function)

```
let mergedBuffer: AudioBuffer = buffers[0];
this.sampleRate = mergedBuffer.sampleRate;
for (let i = 1; i < buffers.length; i++) {
  const tempBuffer: AudioBuffer = this.context.createBuffer(mergedBuffer.numberOfChannels,
    buffers[i].length + mergedBuffer.length, mergedBuffer.sampleRate);
  const channel = tempBuffer.getChannelData(0);
  channel.set(mergedBuffer.getChannelData(0), 0);
  channel.set(buffers[i].getChannelData(0), mergedBuffer.length);
  mergedBuffer = tempBuffer;
}
return mergedBuffer;
```

This code is used to convert float32 to int16

```
let bufferLength = buffer.length - 1;
const intArray = new Int16Array(bufferLength);
while (bufferLength !== -1) {
  const temp = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, buffer[bufferLength]));
  intArray[bufferLength] = temp < 0 ? temp * 0x8000 : temp * 0x7FFF;
  bufferLength--;
}
return intArray;
```

And finally converted array buffer to base64 before sending

```
const binaryString: string = new Uint8Array(intArray)
          .reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), '');
const base64Sring: string = btoa(binaryString);
return base64Sring;
```

I Used Angular HTTPclient for sending to speech api

```
const data = {
  'config': {
    'encoding': 'LINEAR16',
    'sampleRateHertz': this.sampleRate,
    'languageCode': 'en-US'
  },
  'audio': {
    'content': base64
  }
};
console.log(data);
this.httpc.post('https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=' +
'myApiKey', data
).subscribe(
  (res) => {
    console.log(res);
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  }
);
```

This is my first time working with web audio and I think I went wrong  with conversion .

Thanks

Comment: did you get a resolution for it?